# PHP Can't Set Session Token on Form Submittal

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I'm having a problem with my PHP form.  I have an image as the submittal button on my form and I can't seem to set the session token when the form is submitted.  The way the code is written, the token is set upon page load.  That doesn't bother me so much, but I need it to be set or reset when the form is submitted.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Here's the code:

```
<?php
// Initiate the session.
session_start();
// Simple function to return a timestamp.
function microtime_float() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
// Generate the token.
function generateToken() {
    // generate a token from a unique value, took from microtime...
    $token = "myFormToken-" . microtime_float();  

    // Write the generated token to the session variable to check it against the hidden field when the form is sent
    $_SESSION['myFormToken'] = $token; 
    return $token;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>This Is My Webpage...</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click on the image below to be taken to the next page..</h1>
<br /><br />
<!-- BEGIN My Form -->
<form action="http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="myFormToken" value="<?php echo generateToken(); ?>">
<input type="image" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="Click this image!">
</form>
<!-- END My Form -->

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Brian

Comment: You should check if the form submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for not posting this sooner.  Here's the solution I ended-up coming up with.  Please note that some information has been removed to protect my code.  I hope that what I've posted here can still help someone.

```
<?php
// Initiate the session.
session_start();

$myname =""; // Sender Name
$mynameError ="";
$mysoftwarelicensetoken = "";
$mylicensetokenError = "";

// Set this so that we don't go into the function below, until the form posts.
$errors = 1;

// Simple function to replicate PHP 5 behaviour
function microtime_float() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

// Set the token here to prevent any user going to this page and then
//   getting back to the sumbit page.
$_SESSION["myformtoken"] = "myunknowntesttoken";

// Set the variable so that we get into the 'if' section below.
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Checking to see if the form posted.

    $errors = 0;
    //$myname = $_POST["myname"]; // Sender Name
    $mysoftwarelicensetoken = $_POST["mysoftwarelicensetoken"];

    if (!isset($_POST["mysoftwarelicensetoken"])){
        $mylicensetokenError = "You must accept the license agreement";
        $errors = 1;
    } else {
        if ($mysoftwarelicensetoken !== "Yes") {
            $mylicensetokenError = "You must accept the license agreement";
            $errors = 1;
        } else {
            $errors = 0;
        }
    }

    // Set the token again, just for safety's sake.
    $_SESSION["myformtoken"] = "myunknowntesttoken";
}

// This will run when the form posts.
if($errors == 0){
    // Set output SESSION variable. 
    $_SESSION["myformtoken"] = 'myformtoken_intro_' . microtime_float();

    // Re-direct to payment website for payment processing.
    header('Location: https://www.mypaymentwebsite.com');
}
// header("Cache-Control: no cache");
// session_cache_limiter("private_no_expire");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>This Is My Webpage...</head>
<body>
<h1>Click on the image below to be taken to the next page..</h1>
<br /><br />
<!-- BEGIN My Form -->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Do you accept the <a href="mysoftwarelicense.html" class="underlinelink">license agreement</a>?<br />
    You MUST do so to proceed with your purchase.</label>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="mysoftwarelicensetoken" value="Yes" <?php if (isset($mysoftwarelicensetoken) && $mysoftwarelicensetoken == "Yes") echo "checked"; ?> > Yes
<input type="radio" name="mysoftwarelicensetoken" value="No" <?php if (isset($mysoftwarelicensetoken) && $mysoftwarelicensetoken == "No") echo "checked"; ?> > No
</div>
<div class="error"><?php echo $mylicensetokenError;?></div>
<br />
<input class="submit link-button btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy It Now" id="myBuyButton">
</form>
<!-- END My Form -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Initiate the session.
session_start();
// Simple function to return a timestamp.
function microtime_float() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
// Generate the token.
function generateToken() {
    // generate a token from a unique value, took from microtime...
    $token = "myFormToken-" . microtime_float();  

    // Write the generated token to the session variable to check it against the hidden field when the form is sent
      $request = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_METHOD");
   if($request === 'POST')
    $_SESSION['myFormToken'] = $token;
   } else{
$_SESSION['myFormToken'] = $token;
}
    return $token;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>This Is My Webpage...</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click on the image below to be taken to the next page..</h1>
<br /><br />
<!-- BEGIN My Form -->
<form action="http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="myFormToken" value="<?php echo generateToken(); ?>">
<input type="image" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="Click this image!">
</form>
<!-- END My Form -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gufran, thanks for your input.  I have posted the solution I came up with.  Apologies for the unacceptable delay in reply.

Comment: @B.J.Torreano, No problem :)